# Cannot query or do transaction on Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I've created a network which consists of 2 org having two peers each and a solo orderer. It was working fine before load testing after that the orderer went down, but I was still able to retrieve data from the peers. After a while, I restarted the network but now I am unable to query or perform a transaction.

Whenever I am trying to query from cli I am getting:

```
Error: error getting endorser client for query: endorser client failed to connect to peer0.blockit.gatelesis.com:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
```

When I am trying to query from the peer directly I got:

```
Error: error endorsing query: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Failed evaluating policy on signed data during check policy on channel [channel-24] with policy [/Channel/Application/Writers]: [implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied] - proposal response: <nil>
```

At peer logs I got this:

```
2019-08-28 10:00:49.059 UTC [nodeCmd] registerDiscoveryService -> INFO a33d Discovery service activated
2019-08-28 10:00:49.060 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO a33e Starting peer with ID=[name:"peer0.blockit.gatelesis.com" ], network ID=[dev], address=[peer0.blockit.gatelesis.com:7051]
2019-08-28 10:00:49.060 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO a33f Started peer with ID=[name:"peer0.blockit.gatelesis.com" ], network ID=[dev], address=[peer0.blockit.gatelesis.com:7051]
2019-08-28 10:00:49.061 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a340 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.25.0.3:53884
2019-08-28 10:00:49.061 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a341 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.25.0.3:40656
2019-08-28 10:00:49.061 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a342 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.25.0.3:46028
2019-08-28 10:00:49.061 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a343 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.25.0.3:49532
2019-08-28 10:00:49.062 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a344 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.25.0.3:50544
2019-08-28 10:00:49.062 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a345 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.25.0.3:50950
2019-08-28 10:00:49.062 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a346 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.25.0.3:51294
2019-08-28 10:00:49.063 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a347 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.25.0.3:51580
2019-08-28 10:00:49.063 UTC [nodeCmd] func8 -> INFO a348 Starting profiling server with listenAddress = 0.0.0.0:6060
2019-08-28 10:00:49.063 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a349 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.25.0.3:51854
2019-08-28 10:00:49.063 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a34a TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.25.0.3:53742
2019-08-28 10:00:49.064 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a34b TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.25.0.3:52088
2019-08-28 10:00:49.064 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a34c TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.25.0.3:52316
2019-08-28 10:00:49.064 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a34d TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.25.0.5:43472
2019-08-28 10:00:49.064 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a34e TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.25.0.3:52524
2019-08-28 10:00:49.065 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a34f TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.25.0.3:53094
2019-08-28 10:00:49.065 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a350 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.25.0.3:53260
2019-08-28 10:00:49.065 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a351 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.25.0.3:53428
2019-08-28 10:00:49.065 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a352 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.25.0.3:53580
2019-08-28 10:00:49.065 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a353 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.25.0.3:52724
2019-08-28 10:00:49.066 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a354 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.25.0.3:52908
2019-08-28 10:00:49.709 UTC [gossip.election] beLeader -> INFO a355 dfc797622a9f875949601983ffceb8b5e48951174366174209299611544d92bf : Becoming a leader
2019-08-28 10:00:49.709 UTC [gossip.service] func1 -> INFO a356 Elected as a leader, starting delivery service for channel channel-988
2019-08-28 10:00:50.459 UTC [gossip.election] beLeader -> INFO a357 dfc797622a9f875949601983ffceb8b5e48951174366174209299611544d92bf : Becoming a leader
2019-08-28 10:00:50.459 UTC [gossip.service] func1 -> INFO a358 Elected as a leader, starting delivery service for channel channel-989
2019-08-28 10:00:50.895 UTC [gossip.election] beLeader -> INFO a359 dfc797622a9f875949601983ffceb8b5e48951174366174209299611544d92bf : Becoming a leader
2019-08-28 10:00:50.895 UTC [gossip.service] func1 -> INFO a35a Elected as a leader, starting delivery service for channel channel-99
2019-08-28 10:00:51.251 UTC [gossip.election] beLeader -> INFO a35b dfc797622a9f875949601983ffceb8b5e48951174366174209299611544d92bf : Becoming a leader
2019-08-28 10:00:51.251 UTC [gossip.service] func1 -> INFO a35c Elected as a leader, starting delivery service for channel channel-990
2019-08-28 10:00:51.600 UTC [gossip.election] beLeader -> INFO a35d dfc797622a9f875949601983ffceb8b5e48951174366174209299611544d92bf : Becoming a leader
2019-08-28 10:00:51.601 UTC [gossip.service] func1 -> INFO a35e Elected as a leader, starting delivery service for channel channel-991
2019-08-28 10:00:51.950 UTC [gossip.election] beLeader -> INFO a35f dfc797622a9f875949601983ffceb8b5e48951174366174209299611544d92bf : Becoming a leader
2019-08-28 10:00:51.950 UTC [gossip.service] func1 -> INFO a360 Elected as a leader, starting delivery service for channel channel-992
2019-08-28 10:00:52.017 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO a361 unary call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=Ping grpc.request_deadline=2019-08-28T10:00:54.017Z grpc.peer_address=172.25.0.3:54020 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.blockit.gatelesis.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=91.044µs
2019-08-28 10:00:52.020 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO a362 streaming call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=GossipStream grpc.request_deadline=2019-08-28T10:01:02.018Z grpc.peer_address=172.25.0.3:54020 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.blockit.gatelesis.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=1.8267ms
2019-08-28 10:00:52.051 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO a363 unary call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=Ping grpc.request_deadline=2019-08-28T10:00:54.051Z grpc.peer_address=172.25.0.3:54022 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.blockit.gatelesis.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=79.786µs
2019-08-28 10:00:52.308 UTC [gossip.election] beLeader -> INFO a364 dfc797622a9f875949601983ffceb8b5e48951174366174209299611544d92bf : Becoming a leader
2019-08-28 10:00:52.308 UTC [gossip.service] func1 -> INFO a365 Elected as a leader, starting delivery service for channel channel-993
2019-08-28 10:00:52.338 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO a366 streaming call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=GossipStream grpc.peer_address=172.25.0.3:54022 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.blockit.gatelesis.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=285.951264ms
2019-08-28 10:00:52.722 UTC [gossip.election] beLeader -> INFO a367 dfc797622a9f875949601983ffceb8b5e48951174366174209299611544d92bf : Becoming a leader
2019-08-28 10:00:52.722 UTC [gossip.service] func1 -> INFO a368 Elected as a leader, starting delivery service for channel channel-994
2019-08-28 10:00:52.853 UTC [gossip.comm] func1 -> WARN a369 peer1.blockit.gatelesis.com:8051, PKIid:b6112b61b1885609860b91b49516a61a9327cb1b82f79b1c2d09e13a4c30a924 isn't responsive: EOF
2019-08-28 10:00:52.853 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN a36a Entering [b6112b61b1885609860b91b49516a61a9327cb1b82f79b1c2d09e13a4c30a924]
2019-08-28 10:00:52.853 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN a36b Closing connection to Endpoint: peer1.blockit.gatelesis.com:8051, InternalEndpoint: peer1.blockit.gatelesis.com:8051, PKI-ID: b6112b61b1885609860b91b49516a61a9327cb1b82f79b1c2d09e13a4c30a924, Metadata:
2019-08-28 10:00:52.853 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN a36c Exiting
2019-08-28 10:00:52.952 UTC [gossip.election] beLeader -> INFO a36d dfc797622a9f875949601983ffceb8b5e48951174366174209299611544d92bf : Becoming a leader
2019-08-28 10:00:52.952 UTC [gossip.service] func1 -> INFO a36e Elected as a leader, starting delivery service for channel channel-995
2019-08-28 10:00:54.029 UTC [gossip.election] beLeader -> INFO a36f dfc797622a9f875949601983ffceb8b5e48951174366174209299611544d92bf : Becoming a leader
2019-08-28 10:00:54.029 UTC [gossip.service] func1 -> INFO a370 Elected as a leader, starting delivery service for channel channel-996
2019-08-28 10:00:54.378 UTC [gossip.election] beLeader -> INFO a371 dfc797622a9f875949601983ffceb8b5e48951174366174209299611544d92bf : Becoming a leader
2019-08-28 10:00:54.378 UTC [gossip.service] func1 -> INFO a372 Elected as a leader, starting delivery service for channel channel-997
2019-08-28 10:00:54.717 UTC [gossip.election] beLeader -> INFO a373 dfc797622a9f875949601983ffceb8b5e48951174366174209299611544d92bf : Becoming a leader
2019-08-28 10:00:54.717 UTC [gossip.service] func1 -> INFO a374 Elected as a leader, starting delivery service for channel channel-998
2019-08-28 10:00:55.058 UTC [gossip.election] beLeader -> INFO a375 dfc797622a9f875949601983ffceb8b5e48951174366174209299611544d92bf : Becoming a leader
2019-08-28 10:00:55.058 UTC [gossip.service] func1 -> INFO a376 Elected as a leader, starting delivery service for channel channel-999
2019-08-28 10:15:18.931 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO a377 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.25.0.5:44006 error="Failed evaluating policy on signed data during check policy on channel [channel-24] with policy [/Channel/Application/Writers]: [implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied]" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=5.935604ms
2019-08-28 10:15:52.432 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO a378 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.25.0.5:44014 error="Failed evaluating policy on signed data during check policy on channel [channel-24] with policy [/Channel/Application/Writers]: [implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied]" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=507.807µs
2019-08-28 10:18:49.674 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO a379 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.25.0.5:44076 error="Failed evaluating policy on signed data during check policy on channel [channel-24] with policy [/Channel/Application/Writers]: [implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied]" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=439.412µs
```

At orderer logs I got this:

```
2019-08-28 09:52:31.880 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] loadVerifier -> INFO a74 Loaded verifier for channel paradox from config block at index 2673
2019-08-28 09:52:31.881 UTC [orderer.common.server] initializeServerConfig -> INFO a75 Starting orderer with TLS enabled
2019-08-28 09:52:31.900 UTC [orderer.common.server] initializeMultichannelRegistrar -> INFO a76 Not bootstrapping because of existing chains
2019-08-28 09:52:52.091 UTC [orderer.commmon.multichannel] Initialize -> INFO a77 Starting system channel 'paradox' with genesis block hash d771e0c05b145ce05e549e379a4804032833fe2b292cf2b147da975921866ae4 and orderer type solo
2019-08-28 09:52:52.091 UTC [orderer.common.server] Start -> INFO a78 Starting orderer:
Version: 1.4.1
Commit SHA: 87074a7
Go version: go1.11.5
OS/Arch: linux/amd64
2019-08-28 09:52:52.091 UTC [orderer.common.server] Start -> INFO a79 Beginning to serve requests
2019-08-28 09:52:52.093 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a7a TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.25.0.5:55816
2019-08-28 09:52:52.101 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a7b TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.25.0.5:55686
2019-08-28 09:52:52.102 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a7c TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.25.0.5:55560
2019-08-28 09:52:52.102 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a7d TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.25.0.5:55562
2019-08-28 09:52:52.103 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a7e TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.25.0.5:55564
2019-08-28 09:52:52.103 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a7f TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.25.0.5:55566
2019-08-28 09:52:52.103 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a80 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.25.0.5:55568
2019-08-28 09:52:52.104 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a81 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.25.0.5:55570
2019-08-28 09:52:52.104 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a82 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.25.0.5:55572
2019-08-28 09:52:52.105 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a83 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.25.0.5:55574
2019-08-28 09:52:52.108 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a84 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.25.0.5:55576
2019-08-28 09:52:52.108 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a85 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.25.0.5:55578
2019-08-28 09:52:52.109 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a86 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.25.0.5:55580
2019-08-28 09:52:52.109 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a87 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.25.0.5:55582
2019-08-28 09:52:52.110 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a88 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.25.0.5:55584
```

All the nodes are running in docker containers. Any help will be appreciated.

I've attached extended logs for the orderer and peer

**Peer:** https://pastebin.com/DP0gr56h

**Orderer:** https://pastebin.com/GYnEXyax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
2019-08-28 09:52:52.093 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO a7a TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.25.0.5:55816
```

When I carefully observed both Orderer and peer logs I saw below error

TLS handshake failed with error EOF >>> Makes me to think about status of the Orderer and peer

Both trying to connect each other and not able to connect

Comment: But it is the orderer, that too a solo one! How come it has a remote address?

Comment: Remote Address means your client (ask or cli) Orderer is fine it is just complaining that some one is contacted me with wrong certificate or fake certificate

Comment: Ohh, but I haven't changed the certificates but suddenly after trying to query the data for a while on both cli and peer the network started working again. Can it be because of load testing on solo orderer and peers?

Comment: Yes it was Orderer & peer connection issue, I have updated my answer

Comment: But It went down for 2 days and after querying directly for a while it started working again automatically. Is it because of the transactions that the orderer was processing before the crash started processing it when it after stating the service?

Comment: Actually Orderer & peer keeps their ledger & complete data under one location so as long as container is alive data will remain exists and it persist across container restarts. If you remove then you will lost so you can mount for backup purpose

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198683/discussion-between-paradox-and-narendranath-reddy).